# Having issues adding components within a ContainerView dynamically

Tags: ember.js

I have a container view in application level and I wanted to add some components to this container view via some action. The way I do this is :

1) I push some objects to the application controller

2) ContainerView is within the context of application controller, so I observe the length of the array holding the objects mentioned in step 1

3) and then I create the components and append them to the container view

One weird thing I noticed was initially the observer defined in the container view was not triggering, but then I added initialize hook where I log the controller, and then the observer started working for me. This tells me maybe I am not doing something right. Here is my container view:

```
App.MyContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //IF YOU WERE TO COMMENT THIS CONSOLE.LOG THEN THE OBSERVER NEVER GETS HIT WHEN YOU CLICK ON ADD BUTTON. MAYBE CONTROLLER IS NOT SET UP AND IT NEEDS SOME TIME???
        console.log(this.get('controller').toString());
    }.on('init'),

    appendMyComponent: function(){
        console.log("inside the observer");
        this.get('controller.myComponents').forEach(function(comp){
        console.log(this.toString());
        this.pushOject(App.MyTestComponent.create({}));
        }, this);
    }.observes('controller.myComponents.length')
});
```

Do I have to use named outlet and then render the container view within the outlet? Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is a jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xamoxese/2/

Your feedback is much appreciated. Thanks good ppl of stackoverflow.

USING :

Ember      : 1.5.0
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.10.2

Allright some more updates, initially the solution provided by @bmeyers was not working for me although it was working in jsbin. So in my real app mu application.hbs looked like this:

```
{{outlet navbar}}
{{outlet}}
{{outlet modal}}
{{view App.MyContainerView}}
```

but then I re-ordered it as :

```
{{view App.MyContainerView}} 
{{outlet navbar}}
{{outlet}}
{{outlet modal}}
```

and then the solution worked. Now only if I could get rid of that console.log thing :)
Here is updated jsbin that I have added on top of  @bmeyers solution http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xamoxese/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this for you and shown an example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xamoxese/3/edit?html,css,js,output

I didn't fix your issue where you are adding the same components over and over again and never clearing the childView array, but maybe that was your intention.

Basically you do not push to the container view, you need to push to the childViews property.

Hope this helped!

UPDATE FIXED

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xamoxese/6/edit

Ok so looks like you just needed a reference outside your foreach function and that for some reason allowed using it the way it is documented

UPDATE 2:: Change the containerView code to....

```
App.MyContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.appendMyComponent();
  },

  appendMyComponent: function(){
      this.get('controller.myComponents').forEach(function(comp){
        this.pushObject(App.MyTestComponent.create({}));
    }, this);
  }.observes('controller.myComponents.length')
});
```

This just feels a bit cleaner than creating an empty view that you will never use. Picky  I know but it was bugging me.

Comment: Looking at the ember documentation though... it appears you should be able to push directly into the containerView, so as to WHY it wasn't working I'm not sure

Comment: You are right, it is not my intention to add same components repeatedly, but for the purpose of the issue I was getting , I didn't take care of such. It was working but I am getting this "DEPRECATION: Manipulating an Ember.ContainerView through its childViews property is deprecated. Please use the ContainerView instance itself as an Ember.MutableArray.". It doesnot show up in the jsbin but if you were to run it locally, it shows that warning message.

Comment: And that whole console.log stuff still baffles me, if I were to comment it out the solution does not work! I rather not have console.log in my production code.

Comment: Yes that is very odd, no clue as to why that is haha

Comment: I just noticed that if we place our container view above the {{outlet}}, we don;t need to do that self thing. Another weirdness!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to get rid of that console.log thing. So I actually have 2 solutions for this:

1) pass the controller to the container view

```
{{view 'myContainer' controller=this}}
```

2) set an empty view to the ContainerView

```
App.MyContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: [Ember.View.create()],

    appendMyComponent: function(){
        this.get('controller.myComponents').forEach(function(comp){
        this.pushOject(App.MyTestComponent.create({}));
        }, this);
    }.observes('controller.myComponents.length')
});
```

Actually the best solution is as @bmeyers suggested, is to have init function for container view like this:

```
init: function() {     
    this._super();     
    /*
     THIS IS THE OBSERVER METHOD THAT WE HAVE IN THE VIEW, THIS CALL DOES NOT EVEN
     NEED TO ADD A CHILD VIEW, BUT STILL NEEDS TO BE CALLED - STRANGE I KNOW BUT WHY
     I AM NOT SURE. ALSO FACED ISSUE DURING TEST FOR ABOVE 2 APPROACHES, THIS ONE WORKED WELL
     */
    this.appendMyComponent();
}
```

Here is the working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xamoxese/13/

Comment: Hey here is another option, besides creating a blank view in the childviews, and it could potentially be useful if some components already exists.   `App.MyContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.appendMyComponent();
  },

  appendMyComponent: function(){
      this.get('controller.myComponents').forEach(function(comp){
        this.pushObject(App.MyTestComponent.create({}));
    }, this);
  }.observes('controller.myComponents.length')
});    `

Comment: Neat, actually I was getting issue while integration testing Getting error like : Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object
But after adding the init hook as you mentioned, I didn't receive any error. Seems like for containerView we must have a init block. I will update my answer too. If you post it again as an answer, I'll accept it.